# Sed Find and Replace PHP Files in Folders Named Themes

Tags: php, sed, replace

This script is working to find and replace a URLs in PHP files and works very fast when I run it in a test directory with only 1 file.  But, I need to run it from the home directory on my server which is taking forever(at least 5 minutes so far.)  It seems it would be faster if I could narrow the search to not all PHP files but only PHP files in "themes" folders.  There are multiple "themes" folders throughout the server.  Is is possible to narrow search and replace to only php files in folders named "themes"?

```
find . -type f -iname "*.php" -exec sed -i.bak 's/http:\/\/www.changed.com/http:\/\/www.stillchanged.com/g' {} \;
```

**Example Paths to Themes Folder**

/home/site1/public_html/wp-content/themes/

/home/site2/public_html/wp-content/themes/

/home/site3/public_html/wp-content/themes/

Comment: Can you include some example paths for `theme` directory in question.

Comment: See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /tmp/* -type d -iname test\* -exec find {} -type f -iname test\* \;
```

You can do a nested `find` like above.

**Example result:**

```
sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ find /tmp/* -type d -iname test\*
/tmp/stack/test_e
/tmp/stack/test_f
/tmp/stack/test_g
/tmp/stack/test_h
/tmp/stack/test_i
/tmp/stack/test_j
/tmp/stack/test_k
/tmp/test_a
/tmp/test_b
/tmp/test_c
/tmp/test_d
sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ find /tmp/* -type d -iname test\* -exec find {} -type f -iname test\* \;
/tmp/stack/test_e/testa
/tmp/stack/test_e/testb
/tmp/stack/test_e/testc
/tmp/stack/test_e/testd
/tmp/stack/test_f/testa
/tmp/stack/test_f/testb
/tmp/stack/test_f/testc
/tmp/stack/test_f/testd
/tmp/stack/test_g/testa
/tmp/stack/test_g/testb
/tmp/stack/test_g/testc
/tmp/stack/test_g/testd
/tmp/stack/test_h/testa
/tmp/stack/test_h/testb
/tmp/stack/test_h/testc
/tmp/stack/test_h/testd
/tmp/stack/test_i/testa
/tmp/stack/test_i/testb
/tmp/stack/test_i/testc
/tmp/stack/test_i/testd
/tmp/stack/test_j/testa
/tmp/stack/test_j/testb
/tmp/stack/test_j/testc
/tmp/stack/test_j/testd
/tmp/stack/test_k/testa
/tmp/stack/test_k/testb
/tmp/stack/test_k/testc
/tmp/stack/test_k/testd
/tmp/test_a/testa
/tmp/test_a/testb
/tmp/test_a/testc
/tmp/test_a/testd
/tmp/test_b/testa
/tmp/test_b/testb
/tmp/test_b/testc
/tmp/test_b/testd
/tmp/test_c/testa
/tmp/test_c/testb
/tmp/test_c/testc
/tmp/test_c/testd
/tmp/test_d/testa
/tmp/test_d/testb
/tmp/test_d/testc
/tmp/test_d/testd
```

**EDIT:**
In your case you even don't want a nested `find`:

Use `find` like following:

```
find /home/*/public_html/wp-content/themes/ -type f -iname \*.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `-wholename "*themes*"` to the list of your conditions. That will match only files under 'themes' sub-directories (recursively).

Comment: `find . -type f -wholename "*themes*" -iname "*.php" -exec sed -i.bak 's/www.test.com/www.changed.com/g' {} \;` This worked but I had to remove `.bak` because it made `php.bak` of every php file on the server.  I was under the impression that `-i.bak` would only make backup copies of the files that were edited.  Thanks for the help.